# sum value in foreach loop based on another value php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like below. There are id, label, cost, and cid in an array. We want to sum the cost based on the cid like for cid 22 cost should be 196.5 and for cid 11 cost should be 44.4. In our out put array we want to keep the label, cost (sum), and cid, Please see expected output array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1331
            [label] => PM1
            [cost] => 98.25
            [cid] => 22
            [product_id] => 133
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1332
            [label] => PM3
            [cost] => 22.20
            [cid] => 11
            [product_id] => 133
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1341
            [label] => PM1
            [cost] => 98.25
            [cid] => 22
            [product_id] => 134
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1342
            [label] => PM3
            [cost] => 22.20
            [cid] => 11
            [product_id] => 134
        )

)
```

Tried below

```
foreach ($array $key => $value) {

                         $final[$value['cid']] += $value['cost'];
                        } 

                       print_r ($final);
```

Getting below as an output

```
Array
(
    [22] => 196.5
    [11] => 44.4
)
```

Want expected output like below.

```
Array
    (
        [22] =>  Array
           (
            [label] => PM1
            [cost] => 196.5
            [cid] => 22
           )
        [11] => Array
           (
            [label] => PM3
            [cost] => 44.4
            [cid] => 11
           )
    )
```

Basically want to sum cost based on cid and want to keep the label, cost (sum), and cid.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$list = [
    [ 'id' => 1331, 'label' => 'PM1', 'cost' => 98.25, 'cid' => 22, 'product_id' => 133 ],
    [ 'id' => 1332, 'label' => 'PM3', 'cost' => 22.20, 'cid' => 11, 'product_id' => 133 ],
    [ 'id' => 1341, 'label' => 'PM1', 'cost' => 98.25, 'cid' => 22, 'product_id' => 134 ],
    [ 'id' => 1342, 'label' => 'PM3', 'cost' => 22.20, 'cid' => 11, 'product_id' => 134 ]
];

$result = [];

array_walk($list, function ($item) use (&$result) {
  if (isset($result[$item['cid']])) {
    $result[$item['cid']]['cost'] = $item['cost'] + $result[$item['cid']]['cost'];
  } else {
    $result[$item['cid']] = [ 'label' => $item['label'], 'cost' => $item['cost'], 'cid' => $item['cid'] ];
  }
});

print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [22] => Array
        (
            [label] => PM1
            [cost] => 196.5
            [cid] => 22
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [label] => PM3
            [cost] => 44.4
            [cid] => 11
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should do the trick

```
$CIDs_identified = array();
$final_array = array();

foreach($original_array as $small_array){
    if(!in_array($small_array['cid'], $CIDs_identified)){
        $CIDs_identified[] = $small_array['cid'];
        $final_array[$small_array['cid']] = array(
            'label' => $small_array['label'],
            'cost' => $small_array['cost'],
            'cid' => $small_array['cid'],
        );
    }else{
        $final_array[$small_array['cid']]['cost'] += $small_array['cost'];
    
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, But the output is not as expected.

Comment: @skindia how come? I'm getting exactly the output you described as needed - https://3v4l.org/3MKh9

Comment: Yes it is also correct , We made a typo mistake thank you so much. Accepted your solution also.

Answer (score 1):

*On this site, if you can provide your source array in usable format, that is really helpful so that we don't have to retype it. One way to do that is using `var_export`.*

Below is a simple version. Create an array indexed by `cid`. If that item doesn't exist, populate it with the basic data and a zero cost. Then on each loop, including the initial, add the row's cost.

```php
<?php
$data = [
    [
        'id' => 1331,
        'label' => 'PMI',
        'cost' => 98.25,
        'cid' => 22,
        'product_id' => 133,
    ],

    [
        'id' => 1341,
        'label' => 'PMI',
        'cost' => 98.25,
        'cid' => 22,
        'product_id' => 134,
    ],
];

$output = [];
foreach ($data as $item) {
    if (!isset($output[$item['cid']])) {
        $output[$item['cid']] = [
            'label' => $item['label'],
            'cost' => 0,
            'cid' => $item['cid'],
        ];
    }

    $output[$item['cid']]['cost'] += $item['cost'];
}

print_r($output);
```

Demo here: https://3v4l.org/MY6Xu

Comment: thanks @chris its working